# Plot Cumulative Distribution Function from shape, scale, and location parameters

Tags: python, matlab, scipy

After applying Generalised Extreme Value (GEV) theory I have a shape, location, and scale parameter to describe my distribution. Now I'm trying to plot a CDF with these three parameters in Python. In matlab there's a ["cdf" function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/cdf.html) that does this. I cannot find a way to do it with scipy?

Comment: Can you add the code you would have used in MATLAB? From what family is your distribution? Normal, Poisson, Gamma, Binomial, Generalized Extreme Value etc...?

Comment: I am not sure if it is the method you are searching for but have you tried [scipy.stats.norm.cdf](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.norm.html#scipy.stats.norm)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `cdf` method of [`scipy.stats.genextreme`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.genextreme.html).

For example, the following ipython session...

```
In [40]: from scipy.stats import genextreme

In [41]: shape = -0.5

In [42]: loc = 0.0

In [43]: scale = 2.5

In [44]: x = np.linspace(scale/shape, 20, 200)

In [45]: y = genextreme.cdf(x, shape, loc, scale)

In [46]: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

In [47]: plt.plot(x, y, label="GEV CDF")
Out[47]: [<matplotlib.lines.Line2D at 0x10e135790>]

In [48]: plt.legend(loc='best')
Out[48]: <matplotlib.legend.Legend at 0x10de4cc50>
```

generates this plot:

[image: plot]

Note that the shape parameter `c` in the scipy code has the opposite sign of the shape parameter ξ used in the [wikipedia article on the generalized extreme value distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_extreme_value_distribution).

Comment: That's it. Thanks for your help.